# javascript progress bar length at pause

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a problem with audio and progress bar tracking in javascript. I'm using p5.js.

Progress bar tracks music duration while it is playing, but resets to 0 when paused and reverts back to current time when playing again.

HTML is non-existent and not needed, css also.

JS dependencies are p5.js, p5.dom.js and p5.sound.js

```
function draw() {
//this function is called once every frame (once every 1/60 seconds)
//other stuff that has no relation to this problem
musicDuration();
}

//global variables
var music = loadSound(music.mp3);
var currentTimePause = [];

function musicDuration() {
    var currentTimePerc = (music.currentTime() / music.duration()) * width;

// text giving current music time / duration
    strokeWeight(0);
    fill(0, 100, 100);
    textSize(14);
    text(leadingZeroTime(floor(music.currentTime() / 60)) + ':' + leadingZeroTime(floor(music.currentTime() % 60)) + ' / ' + leadingZeroTime(floor(music.duration() / 60)) + ':' + leadingZeroTime(floor(music.duration() % 60)), repairTimerPosition(currentTimePerc - 43), 25, 86);

    //drawing music duration bar
    noStroke();
    fill(190, 70, 70);
    rect(0, 0, width, 10);

     // check if music is playing and return array containing current song position
    if (music.isPlaying()) {
        for (i = 0; i < music.currentTime(); i++) {
            currentTimePause[i] = currentTimePerc;
            console.log(currentTimePause[currentTimePause.length - 1]);
            // filling progress bar along the music.curentTime
            fill(0, 85, 85);
            rect(0, 0, currentTimePerc, 10);
        }
    }
    //if music is paused only draw rectangle second to last value in array, because last is 0. And stop updating array
    else if (music.isPaused()) {
        fill(0, 85, 85);
        rect(0, 0, currentTimePause[currentTimePause.length - 1], 10);
        currentTimePause.length = 0;
        console.log(currentTimePause[currentTimePause.length - 1]);
    } 
}
```

`music.currentTime()` - returns current time of the song in seconds.
`music.duration()` - returns duration of song in seconds.

I tried reseting the array after bar is drawn and setting its length to 0 after the bar is drawn but the value returns to 0. My assumption to why it is still reseting is because it is being called every frame, so maybe the function drew the bar at correct length, but returned to 0 or undefined the second frame.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] instead of a link to a whole repo?

Comment: @KevinWorkman updated the question and hopefully, this is more understandable